# Conditional Spinner

Tags: java, android

I've one problem. I've created spinner, and everything app runs without crashing, but it won't change value of int price, neither setText doesn't work

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button calculateBtn;
EditText userEcts;
TextView ectsPrice;
TextView summary;
Spinner courses;
String cors;
int price = 200;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    userEcts = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ects_input);
    summary = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_summary);
    courses = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.course_spinner);

    calculateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    calculateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //When the button is clicked, call the calculate method.
            calculate();
        }
    });

    final String[] courseArray = new String[4];
    {
        courseArray[0] = "Preddiplomski studij Menadžment";
        courseArray[1] = "Preddiplomski studij Promet";
        courseArray[2] = "Preddiplomski Upravni studij";
        courseArray[3] = "Specijalistički studij Menadžment";
    }

    ArrayAdapter courseAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, courseArray);
    courseAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    courses.setAdapter(courseAdapter);

    courses.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                   View view, int pos, long id) {

            //Get item from Spinner and store in string conductorSize........
            cors = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            if (cors.equals(0)) {
                ectsPrice.setText("200");
                price = 200;
            } else if (cors.equals(1)) {
                ectsPrice.setText("250");
                price = 250;
            } else if (cors.equals(2)) {
                ectsPrice.setText("300");
                price = 300;
            } else if (cors.equals(3)) {
                ectsPrice.setText("350");
                price = 350;
            } else {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    });
}

public void calculate() {
    //gets entered text from the EditText,and convert to integers.
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(userEcts.getText().toString())) {
        Double ects = Double.parseDouble(userEcts.getText().toString());
        //do the calculation
        Double calculatedPrice = ects * price;
        //set the value to the TextView, to display on screen.
        summary.setText("Ukupno za platit: " + Double.toString(calculatedPrice) + "kn");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Niste unijeli broj bodova", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    calculate();
}
```

}

So, on selecting item on position 0, I want to setText to specific text, and change price. Can anyone help?

Comment: use POJO instead string ... like `class course { String name; int price; }` override toString method and let it returns name ... then cast `getItemAtPosition` result to `course` ... `cors` is a string so it cannot be equals 0,1,2,3 ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the position number to check the condition.

```
String[] courseArray = new String[4];
    {
        courseArray[0] = "Preddiplomski studij Menadžment";
        courseArray[1] = "Preddiplomski studij Promet";
        courseArray[2] = "Preddiplomski Upravni studij";
        courseArray[3] = "Specijalistički studij Menadžment";
    }

    ArrayAdapter courseAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, courseArray);
    courseAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    courses.setAdapter(courseAdapter);

    courses.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                   View view, int pos, long id) {

            //Get item from Spinner and store in string conductorSize........
            cors = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            if (cors.equals(courseArray[0])) {
                ectsPrice.setText("200");
                price = 200;
            } else if (cors.equals(courseArray[1])) {
                ectsPrice.setText("250");
                price = 250;
            } else if (cors.equals(courseArray[2])) {
                ectsPrice.setText("300");
                price = 300;
            } else if (cors.equals(courseArray[3])) {
                ectsPrice.setText("350");
                price = 350;
            } else {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: then try comparing the value at position with courseArray, see the edit.

Comment: post the stack trace from logcat

Comment: Is cors an Object or a String? If it is an Object then change it to String.

Comment: Then you need to post full code because this looks fine.

Comment: Try this, when the app crashes open logcat and select your application package name from dropdown box and then post stack trace. Some times Android Studio does not show the stack trace even i the application is selected.

Comment: So the problem is TextView ectsPrice is not initialized. Initialize it in onCreate() using its unique id.

Comment: ectsPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uniqueid); // replace uniqueid with its real id

Comment: thanks man !! I can't believe i skipped that initialization ... I convinced myself that I initialized it ... :D

Comment: No problem.. at least I deserve a vote or mark as answer don't you think so?

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch statment :

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                               View view, int pos, long id) {

        switch(pos){
            case 0:
              ectsPrice.setText("200");
              price = 200;
              break;
            case 1:
              ectsPrice.setText("250");
              price = 250;
              break;
            case 2:
              ectsPrice.setText("300");
              price = 300;
              break;
            case 3:
              ectsPrice.setText("350");
              price = 350;
              break;
        }
  }
```